# Adding to relational database rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rails-activerecord

I have a two models an address model

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :address1, :address2, :country, :county, :customer_id, :town
belongs_to :customer    
end
```

And a customer model

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :email, :firstname, :lastname, :password, :phone
has_one :address

end
```

I have CRUD functionality which I generated using a scaffold. What I want to be able to do is when I am adding a new customer, I can select an address for the customer from the addresses on file or select no address. I am able to view a customer and there their address using this.

```
def showaddress
@customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
@address = @customer.address
respond_to do |format|
format.html # show.html.erb
format.xml { render :xml => @customer }
end
end
```

This is my current controller used to create a new customer

```
def new
@customer = Customer.new

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @customer }
end
end
```

So basically what I want to do is when I am creating a new customer, there is a drop down list of address which the user can click to associate the address with the customer

Comment: are you sure you want a one-to-one relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize a variable of all the addresses in **new** method in controller, and use that variable in view page for populate the select box in the form.

```
def new
  @customer = Customer.new
  @addresses = Address.all
  #...
end
```

or directly populate the addresses in the form as shown below

```
select_tag 'address_id', options_for_select(Address.all.collect{ |a| [a.name, a.id] })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<%= select_tag :address_id, Customer.all.collect {|p| [ p.address_title, p.id ] } %>
```

Comment: I added that to my view and it caused and error heres the code for the view the erroe i got was undefined local variable or method `f'

<h1>New customer</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>
<%= f.select :address_id, Job.all.collect {|p| [ p.address_title, p.id ] } %>

<%= link_to 'Back', customers_path %>

Comment: for which condition you want to use dropdoen?